# New navbar accessibility issues

Tags: bug, status-deferred, top-bar

Two bugs, really. Originally a comment on the announcement post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/#comment-3154973705

## Bug #1: `tabindex="1"` on the search field

I suspect you want it to be the first item a user tabs to on the page, but you can do that just by putting the search box first in the DOM (in the raw HTML).

### Why this is a problem for keyboard users:

After entering a search term, the next interactive element in the tab order is the logo, not the submit button. Remember, not all users hit the Enter key to immediately submit. I do not; that is how I found this issue.

### Why this is a problem for screen reader users:

After allowing the screen reader to describe the controls, the search control is not the first item but appears after the navigation items. Once I start tabbing to the control it is not where I expected (the 8th tab stop) and confuses me about where I am on the page. In addition, I cannot tab directly to the submit button (as outlined above).

### Ideal solution:

Put the search box first in the DOM (in the raw HTML). This removes the risky endeavor of positive `tabindex` values, because once one is added, more tend to appear. For reference, some `tabindex` best practices: http://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html

## Bug #2: The search field has no accessible name

I understand you want an uncluttered design, but without an accessible name the field has no real label.

### Why this is a problem for screen reader users:

The field is only announced as editable. If there is already a pre-populated value in the field then that may be announced. This can be confusing as it offers no context. If there is no value, not all browsers expose the `placeholder` value to assistive technology.

### Ideal solution:

Add a `<label>`. You can use CSS to visually hide it and still make it accessible. Some CSS you can use to make this work: https://medium.com/@jessebeach/beware-smushed-off-screen-accessible-text-5952a4c2cbfe

For reference, I also made a demo of a similar approach to yours from which you may steal code: http://adrianroselli.com/2015/12/responsive-progressive-accessible-vanilla-search.html

### Less ideal solution:

Add an `aria-label` attribute to the field: `<input … aria-label="Search">`

This may be the easier solution, but I recommend not relying on ARIA when a regular HTML `<label>` can do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback. We're looking into this and will get back to you soon.

Comment: Let me know if you need some quick testing. The keyboard part should be easy, the screen reader part less so if you are not familiar with them.

Comment: Interesting, I would have assumed a screen reader would read out the prompt text in such a case, rather than making developers add invisible labels

Comment: It is up to the browsers to pass the info to the screen reader. Also, nobody is making developers add invisible labels. "Prompt" text, or a`placeholder` is widely understood to be bad for UX and accessibility. Best practice is to include a visible `<label>` but designers often do not want them, so developers have an option using off-screen text or ARIA to make up for non-inclusive design decisions. IOW, this is not he fault nor responsibility of the screen reader but the designers/developers.

Comment: You know what they say [about assumption](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=assumptions) @Rob...

Comment: *"After entering a search term, the next interactive element in the tab order is the logo, not the submit button."* Actually, for me, tab out of the search box jumps down to the bottom of the page and gets the "your answer" box next. (Chrome, Windows)

Comment: Mine goes: Search input box -> Your answer input -> Post your answer button -> Logo -> Questions -> Tags -> Users -> Search submit button (although it isn't visible as it hides when you focus away from the text box) -> the rest of the stuff on the nav bar from left to right.

Comment: @JasonC Yep, you are correct. As I do not have an 'answer' box on my _own_ question I was not seeing it. It has a `tabindex` as well: `<textarea id="wmd-input" … tabindex="101">` So does the button right after it: `<input id="submit-button" … tabindex="110">` So, on the whole, that is a far more confusing experience than even what I outlined. All instances of `tabindex` should go, but this bug is about the new top-bar.

Comment: thanks for reporting that. accessibility is super important. we will look into those issues.

Comment: @Paweł should I open a separate issue for the other `tabindex` attributes that @JasonC found or are you tracking that already?

Comment: you can open another issue. tabindex across SO probably needs some more investigation.

Comment: Not about the new top bar, but related in that it seems to be more tabindex weirdness affecting accessibility: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345318 cc @Paweł